# How to solve Nextflow error: "Trace file already exists"?

Tags: assembly, sars-cov-2, nextflow, workflow-management

When trying to run epi2me-labs/wf-artic, I get the following error:

```
❯ nextflow run epi2me-labs/wf-artic \
 -r v0.3.18 --fastq  ~/Downloads/barcode95.fastq.gz \
 --scheme_version Midnight-ONT/V3 

N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.10.1
Launching `https://github.com/epi2me-labs/wf-artic` [ecstatic_marconi] DSL2 - revision: a60a1e1e73 [v0.3.18]
Trace file already exists: /Users/corneliusromer/Downloads/BJGMC_ONT_Run71/output/execution/trace.txt
```

It seems that nextflow doesn't like to rerun after it failed. Is there a convenient way to force nextflow to rerun, in a similar way to `snakemake --force-rerun`? Or do I need to manually delete the trace file every time? That works, but it's tedious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rotation of report files (trace, execution, timeline etc) was removed recently (since version [22.10.0](https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/releases/tag/v22.10.0) in [`a762ed5`](https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/commit/a762ed59c1af255183da8a2d26907206964eade0)). To overwrite the existing trace file you will need to add the following to your Nextflow [config](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/config.html):

```
trace.overwrite = true
```

See: https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/issues/3317